# jquery trigger works from click but no in on ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, triggers, ready

I have some checkboxes which trigger an ajax search. I want to check the boxes automatically and trigger the search. If I run the triggers from a button click, it works fine. But if I add them to the initial load function, the checkboxes are checked but the triggers don't work. Why? 
Here is the code 
first I uncheck all the boxes.

```
jQuery( "[id^='radio_']" ).prop('checked', false );
```

Then I trigger checking certain boxes.

```
jQuery('#radio_2155').trigger('click');
jQuery('#radio_1775').trigger('click');
```

Edit to clarify: this works when I click on ".entry-title"
All the checkboxes are unchecked, certain boxes are checked and the search is triggered.

```
jQuery('.entry-title').click(
    function(event){
         jQuery( "[id^='radio_']" ).prop('checked', false );           
         jQuery('#radio_2155').trigger('click');
        jQuery('#radio_1775').trigger('click');
    }
);
```

In this version, the alert works, the boxes are unchecked, and then certain boxes are checked, but they don't trigger the search.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function(){
        alert('this works');
            jQuery( "[id^='radio_']" ).prop('checked', false );     
            jQuery('#radio_2155').trigger('click');
            jQuery('#radio_1775').trigger('click');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: How do you trigger search on radio check, what events.

Comment: In one version I'm triggering it with a click. In the other version I'm triggering it in on load in  jQuery(function(){

Answer (score 0):

Where in the code do you add the click action to the checkbox. From your description it seems like you call the trigger before the actual click action is added to the boxes.

did you try calling the trigger at the end of your $.ready fuction ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "add the click action". All I'm doing is triggering a click.

Comment: what other scripts are you loading. i think in this case the script containing your triggers should be added as last in your html